# Symfony2 / Validation - NotBlank validation doesn't work

Tags: validation, symfony

I have issue with Assert/NotBlank().
It just doesn't work. 
Every time when I send a blank form, I see 500, `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column '***' cannot be null` instead of some error.

I have this in entity: 
`use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;`

```
    ...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $text;
   ...
```

**EXTRA:
Controller:**
Controller, for adding ads to the database.

```
public function insertAdAction($categoryId, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $category = $em->getRepository('DbBundle:Category')->findAll();
        $ads = new Ads();
        $form = $this->createForm(new InsertAdType(), $ads, array(
            'categoryId' => $categoryId,
            'name' => $request->cookies->get('name'),
            'phone' => $request->cookies->get('phone'),
            'email' => $request->cookies->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->cookies->get('password'),

        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            try {
                $user = new User();
                $validator = $this->get('validator');
                $validator->validate($ads);
                $byCategory = $em->getRepository('DbBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => $categoryId), array());
                $categoryName = $byCategory->getName();
                $phone = $form['phone']->getData();
                $ads->setCategory($categoryName);
                $ads->setCategoryUrl($this->get('WebPortalBundle')->seoUrl($categoryName));
                $ads->setCountry($form['country']->getData());
                $ads->setText(nl2br($form['text']->getData()));
                $ads->setTitleUrl($this->get('WebPortalBundle')->seoUrl($form['title']->getData()));
                $ads->setSubcategoryUrl($this->get('WebPortalBundle')->seoUrl($form['subcategory']->getData()));
                $ads->setIp($request->getClientIp());
                if (!$em->getRepository('DbBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('phone' => $form['phone']->getData()))) {
                    $user->setPhone($phone);
                    $em->persist($user);
                }
                $ads->setPath(implode(',', $this->uploadImg($form['file']->getData())));
                $em->persist($ads);
                $em->flush();
                $response = new Response();
                $time = time() + 31536000;
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', $form['name']->getData(), $time));
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('email', $form['email']->getData(), $time));
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('phone', $form['phone']->getData(), $time));
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('password', $form['password']->getData(), $time));
                $response->send();
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                throw new \ErrorException;
            }
        }
        return $this->render('WebPortalBundle:Default/InsertAd:insertAd.html.twig', array('category' => $category, 'insertForm' => $form->createView()), $this->get('WebPortalBundle')->cache($request));
    }
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code in your controller?

Comment: Do you [validate form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-and-forms) on submit? That annotation is not enough by itself.

Comment: I tried to add this `$validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($ads);`, but still 500

Comment: Why did you asterisk the column name; i.e: `Column '***' cannot be null`? I assume this says `text`?

Comment: It shows all my columns where is  nullable=false.
If nullable=true it creates empty row.

Comment: Did you enable validation through annotation in your config file?

Comment: If I am right, `nullable` annotation property only serves a single purpose: Recreate DB schema model from your classes (migration/sync process). It  should not have to do anything with actual data constraints...

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you have no `setDefaultOptions` method in your form type.

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
...

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DBBundle\Entity\Ads',
        ));
    }
```

Comment: I have this in formtype

`public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'categoryId' => null,
            'name' => null,
            'phone' => null,
            'email' => null,
            'password' => null,
            'data_class' => 'DbBundle\Entity\Ads',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        ));
    }`

`setDefaultOptions` is deprecated

Comment: You'r right, i just copy pasta the code. So have no idea whats wrong with that.